# Getting Smackx PubSub working

Tags: java, openfire, publish-subscribe

I've got the following code:

```
        PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connection, "pubsub.openfire.local");
        LeafNode myNode = (LeafNode) manager.createNode("NewNode", form);

        SimplePayload payload = new SimplePayload("session", "pubsub:NewNode:session", "<sessionId>1234</sessionId>");


        // putting null for id means you let server generate id
        PayloadItem<SimplePayload> item = new PayloadItem<SimplePayload>(null, payload);

        // you could use publish() for asynchronous call
        myNode.send(item);
```

and I continuously get the following error on trying to send the node value:

> conflict(409)
>     at >org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.packet.SyncPacketSend.getReply(SyncPacketSend.java:53)
>     at >org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.packet.SyncPacketSend.getReply(SyncPacketSend.java:61)
>     at >org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager.sendPubsubPacket(PubSubManager.java:324)
>     at >org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager.sendPubsubPacket(PubSubManager.java:318)
>     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager.createNode(PubSubManager.java:134)
>     at PubSubPublisher.main(PubSubPublisher.java:33)

Would love any ideas about how to debug, or move forward with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The node you are trying to create already exists. Call [getNode](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/pubsub/PubSubManager.html#getNode%28java.lang.String%29) and/or [deleteNode](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/pubsub/PubSubManager.html#deleteNode%28java.lang.String%29) first and then `createNode`. Wrap your code in a `try/catch` block to handle the `XMPPException` that may be thrown.

```
LeafNode myNode = null;
try{
  try{
    LeafNode existingNode = manager.getNode("NewNode");  
    //exists, so delete
    manager.deleteNode("NewNode");
  }catch(XMPPException e){
    //'getNode' threw an exception.
    //so we know that the node did not exist
  }
  myNode = (LeafNode) manager.createNode("NewNode", form);
}catch(XMPPException e){
  System.err.println(e);
}
```